# How to convert any base to base 10 for big numbers

Tags: c++

I want to convert a big number (100,000 digits) from any base to base 10. I'm using this code: 
this is reading file method

```
string* ReadFile(string fileName) {

ifstream inFile(fileName);
string line;
string* myArray = new string[1000000];

if (inFile.is_open()) {

    int count = 0;
    while (getline(inFile, line)) {
        myArray[count] = line;
        count++;
    }
    inFile.close();

}
else
{
    cout << "file is not open";
}

return myArray;}
```

convert every character to base 10 method

```
int val(char c){
if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
    return (int)c - '0';
else
    return (int)c - 'A' + 10; }
```

any base to decimal

```
int Base2Dec(string* arr) {

int base = stoi(arr[0]);
string str = "";

int size = 0;
while (!arr[size].empty())
    ++size;

for (int i = size; i > 0; i--) {
    str += arr[i];
}

int len = str.length();

int power = 1;
int num = 0;  

for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (val(str[i]) >= base)
    {
        printf("Invalid Number");
    }

    num += val(str[i]) * power;
    power = power * base;
}

return num;}
```

and main method

```
int main(){
string* A = ReadFile("A2.txt"); cout << Base2Dec(A);
string* B = ReadFile("B.txt"); Base2Dec(B);

cin.get();}
```

it works but not for 100,000 digits ?! I know int type is limited and I am not allowed to use int64 so, I want to know what the solution is?!

Comment: Tell us more about what doesn't work. How doesn't it work? You may in fact be running out of memory, as 100,000 strings could take up quite a bit of space on the heap.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment or an online test quiz?

Comment: Convert to a string of decimal digits, not to an integer.

Comment: As you know int type can not hold big numbers. in fact I want to know how i can use string array instead of int ?!

Comment: Why not go with a new class that can store decimals of any size? Like class NaturalNumber{private: vector<char> digits; public: NaturalNumber& operator +=(const NaturalNumber& to_add); ... } that is able to add two numbers by digits, like a pupil would do? Or, a little bit more sophisticated, uses several digits per char entry.